# Database closing in for loop

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok I am getting some weirdness with the database connection closing without me closing it. Here is the code.

```
boolean dbOpen = database.isOpen();

    for (PlanModel plan : plans) {
        dbOpen = database.isOpen();
        Map<MessierObjectModel, NoteModel> planObjects = new HashMap<MessierObjectModel, NoteModel>();
        query = "select astro_plan_entry_id, messier_catalog_id from astro_plan_entry where astro_plan_id = " + plan.getPlanId();


        cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        dbOpen = database.isOpen();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                NoteModel objectNote = getPlanObjectNote(cursor.getInt(0));
                planObjects.put(getMessierObject(cursor.getInt(1)), objectNote);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        plan.setPlanObjects(planObjects);

        cursor.close();
    }

    close();
```

The first run through the loop the database stays open the whole time. However, the second time through dbOpen is false. I can't figure out why this is happening, and **database** is a class field and it doesn't get closed until the close() method is called.

**EDIT**: Ok it looks like it's closing from **cursor.moveToNext()**. Or at least if I check right after the while loop it is closed. I still don't know what is happening but at least it's a step forward.

Comment: Maybe side effect of call `getPlanObjectNote()` or `getMessierObject()`? You could try to replace these calls by some mockup code or just comment out the whole code in the `do ... while` loop

Comment: Yes indeed that was that case. Thanks! I need to look more into proper db management on android. I'm not doing it right.